# mongodb authorization exception in JMeter : code13

Tags: mongodb, jmeter

In MongoDB 3.2 I've setup a user with  rights:

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "username",
    pwd: "pass",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "dbname" }]

     }
)

db.auth("username", "pass" )
```

When I use the JMeter(2.13) to connect to the database (using Jmeter's elements MongoDB Source Config , MongoDB Script) and run a query like this:

```
db.mycollectionname.find()
```

I get this error:

```
error: { "$err" : "not authorized on dbname to execute command { $eval: \"db.mycollectionname.find()\", args: [] }" , "code" : 13}
```

While I have provided all the necessary details Server Address List , Database , User , Password to Jmeter's MongoDB Source Config , MongoDB Script respectively.

Any ideas what can be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had to set up a user with **eval permissions** even though this is not recommended (even the admin user does not have these permissions).

Try that and change you script to look at the new user and it should work.